# Sonar Web API: /api/qualityprofiles/backup failure using v6.7.1 or v6.7.3

Tags: api, curl, sonarqube

I am attempting to create a backup of all rules from one Sonar instance. Searching for an example of how to resolve or work around this stack trace, I've not yet found a solution. Note that the curl provides no output, and I *can* produce output for a curl such as `$ curl -u <username>:<password> http://<domain>/api/rules/search?languages=java`. Thanks for the help!

Reuqest: `$ curl -u <username>:<password> http://<domain>/api/qualityprofiles/backup`

Log output of `/opt/sonarqube-6.7.1/logs/web.log`:

> 2018.05.03 15:36:51 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.w.RootFilter] Processing of request /api/qualityprofiles/backup failed
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call reset() after response has been committed
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.reset(ResponseFacade.java:348)
>       at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletResponse$ServletStream.reset(ServletResponse.java:79)
>       at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.sendErrors(WebServiceEngine.java:135)
>       at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:105)
>       at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:86)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
>       at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:72)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**EDIT**: Please note that I installed 6.7.3, ran the same curl as listed above, and received the same log output in web.log.